# Connecting an android phone to a server over http and outputstream

Tags: android, apache, http

I am trying to connect an android phone to a server running on my local machine over http and outputstream the content but unsuccessful..!

here is my code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.24.42:80/DebugServer/");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();     
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        readStream(in);
        urlConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}


private void readStream(InputStream in) {

    try {
        in.read();
        in.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: Arent u supposed to connect to port 8080 ???

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.24.42:80/DebugServer/");
```

is your connection URL. Change the port to `8080` because that is where the server listens to.

Also, did you go to the `bin` folder of your `tomcat` (I am assuming that here) and run the `startup.BAT` or `startup.SH` file because without that your server is not running.

To check if your server is properly running, try `http://localhost:8080`
And please, post the logcat :)